# How to get access to StateNotifier state in HookWidget?

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

We can create a  `StateNotifierProvider` like this:

```
final provider = StateNotifierProvider((ref) => CounterNotifier());
```

To access provider in `HookWidget`, we can use `useProvider` like this:

```
final counterModel = useProvider(provider);
```

But how to get state? The below code used to work till last year but does not work now:

```
final counterModel = useProvider(provider.state);
```

Now it says the getter state isn't defined. So how to get access to the state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Riverpod 0.14.0, the way we work with StateNotifier is a bit different.

Now, state is the default property exposed, so to listen to the state, simply:

```dart
final counterModel = useProvider(provider);
```

To access any functions, etc. on your StateNotifier, access the notifier:

```dart
final counterModel = useProvider(provider.notifier);
```

And now when we create StateNotifierProviders, we include the type of the state of the StateNotifier:

```dart
final provider = StateNotifierProvider<CounterNotifier, CounterModel>((ref) => CounterNotifier());
```

See more on the changes from 0.13.0 -> 0.14.0 [here](https://riverpod.dev/docs/migration/0.13.0_to_0.14.0).